# Printing an array in reverse

Tags: c++

## Task

You'll be given an array of N integers and you have to print the integers in the reverse order.

## Constraints

1<=N<=1000

1<=A_i<=10000, where A_i is the ith integer in the array.

## Input

4

1 2 3 4

## Output

4 3 2 1

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int N, y; //declaring N as the length of array
    cin >> N; //intakes the length as an input
    if (N>=1 && N<=1000){ //checks whether the length satisfies the rules
        int a[N]; // makes an array containing N elements
        for (int x =1; x<N; x++){ //starts transcription on the array
            cin>>y; //temporarily assigns the input on a variable
            if (y>=1&&y<=10000){ //checks if the input meets rules
                a[x]=y; //copies the variable on the array 
            }        
        }

        for (int z = N; z>1; z--){ //runs a loop to print in reverse
            cout<<a[z]<<endl;
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Problem

Obtained output is

-1249504352

3

2

Indicating an error in transcription.

## Question

Can somebody please tell me where I am making a mistake? Secondly, is it possible to directly check whether an input is meeting requirement rather than temporarily declaring a variable for it?

Comment: This code won't compile. And `int a[N];` is not standard C++ anyway. Also your output loop accesses the array out of bounds

Comment: Some-one (your teacher, I suspect) has `#include`d `<vector>`, though you are not using it. This might be a clue as to what to use instead of an array like that...

Comment: In an array `a[N]` the `N` is the size, not the last index. Valid values for the index are 0 to N-1.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes thank you I was able to figure out the mistake. Can you answer the last question on my post?

Comment: @Default How was no attempt shown? I clearly provided the code I wrote. I properly provided my background understandings of uses of all line in form of comments. How is this not an "attempt"?

Comment: for what it's worth, I disagree that there was no attempt. I think the downvotes are probably because you formatted the question as if you were copying the assignment description, and people did not read closely enough to see your attempt.

Comment: Because you haven't even shown what the "mistake" is. You dumped some code and asked others to inspect it. There seems to be no attempt to minimize the example. There are currently 3 potential things you might want help with - input via `cin`, allocating an array, figuring out the size of an array.. That to me means no attempt.

Comment: "mistake" as in, does it not compile? Is it the incorrect output? Do you not get the correct input? Does the program hang?

Comment: @mathnoob123 - No, there is no way to ask for input in a specific range. But it is also not expensive to have an extra variable (or to give them longer and more descriptive names).

Comment: @Default I have modified my question to include the "mistake" which you requested for. I hope this gives enough grounds for the retraction of downvote.

Comment: @Default Please look at the edited question again.

Comment: Your teacher should've told you that writing code may seem like it's the hardest thing in programming; but it's not.  Debugging is.  They should've given you some basic pointers as to how to use your debugger.  Since it seems that they haven't; firstly I suggest you ask your teacher explicitly for help on that; secondly I suggest you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ which should help you not just with this task, but all future tasks

Comment: @UKMonkey I am self-learning. No teachers to guide me.

Comment: @mathnoob123 in that case - I would highlight the link even more strongly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in idiomatic `c++11`, using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which is a dynamically resizable container useful for applications like this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cin >> size; // take in the length as an input

    // check that the input satisfies the requirements,
    // use the return code to indicate a problem
    if (size < 1 || size > 1000) return 1;

    std::vector<int> numbers; // initialise a vector to hold the 'array'
    numbers.reserve(size);    // reserve space for all the inputs

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int num;
        std::cin >> num; // take in the next number as an input

        if (num < 1 || num > 10000) return 1;

        numbers.push_back(num);
    }

    std::reverse(numbers.begin(), numbers.end()); // reverse the vector

    // print each number in the vector
    for (auto &num : numbers) {
        std::cout << num << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A few things to note:

- `using namespace std` is considered bad practice most of the time. Use (e.g.) `std::cin` instead for things which come from the `std` namespace.
- `numbers.reserve(size)` is not necessary for correctness, but will make the program faster by reserving space in advance.
- `for ( auto &num : numbers )` uses a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), available in `c++11` and later versions.

Comment: Some checking for stream failures after reading from cin would be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You could make your `for` loop indices go from high to low:

```
for (int i = N-1; i > 0; --i)
{
  std::cout << a[i] << "\n";  // Replace '\n' with space for horizontal printing.
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

This would apply with `std::vector` as well.

With `std::vector`, you can use a reverse iterator.  There are other techniques available (as in other answers).